# Can I localize the hash reference in a Moose attribute via the accessor?

Tags: perl, moose

I have a Moose object with an attribute that contains a hash reference.

```perl
package Foo;

use Moose;

has bar => (
  is => 'ro',
  isa => 'HashRef',
  default => sub { {} },
};
```

In my code, I want to `local` the hash reference that is inside `$foo->bar`. I know I can do:

```perl
my $foo = Foo->new;

# ...

my %local_bar = ( asdf => 123 );
local $foo->{bar} = \%local_bar;   # THIS LINE

call_to_something_that_needs_bar($foo);

for (keys %local_bar) {
  ...
}
```

But I don't want to do that<sup>1</sup>. Is there syntax to localize that structure without going to the internals?

---

<sup>1) The reason I don't want to do that is that `$foo` is wrapped in an [Object::Destroyer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Object::Destroyer) instance, so while `$foo->bar` resolves to Foo, `$foo->{bar}` actually ends up in the destroyer instance, and `$foo->{object}->{bar}` is where `$foo->bar` goes. The code with the `local` is in production code, but the `$foo` object is only an Object::Destroyer instance in a test.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`local` makes a backup of a variable, then places a directive on the stack that restores that variable when it's popped off the stack. The following does something similar:

```perl
use Object::Destroyer qw( );

sub local_attribute {
   my $obj  = shift;
   my $attr = shift;
   my $val  = shift;  # Optional

   my $backup = $obj->$attr();
   my $guard = Object::Destroyer->new(
      sub {
         $obj->$attr( $backup )
      }
   );

   $obj->$attr( $val );

   return $guard;
}

my $guard = local_attribute( $foo, "bar", \%local_bar );
```

The above uses object destruction to provide a generic approach. You could also use case-specific exception handling.

Comment: Maybe with Scope::Guard rather than Object::Destroyer?

Comment: @simbabque I originally used Sub::ScopeFinalizer, but switched to Object::Destroyer since they're already using that one. Whatever.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the internal workings of `local` better now.

Comment: Do you mind if I turn this into a CPAN release?